# Perl-regex word boundary equivalence

Tags: regex, perl, equivalence, word-boundary

I read that the regex

```
\ba
```

is equivalent to

```
(?<!\w)a
```

but before that I had figured out that maybe

```
^a|\Wa
```

is equivalent too

My question is: What is the difference between those two? Could somebody write an example if they are not equivalent?

Comment: `(?<!\w)` only matches at the beginning of a word where `\b` will assert at either end of a word.

Comment: @dawg yes, but `a` is a word character, which means that in `\ba`, `\b` can only be satisfied by the case where the nonword is on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` is equivalent to `(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))`, so

`\ba` is equivalent to `(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))a`, so

`\ba` is equivalent to `(?<!\w)a` because `a` matches `\w`.

---

Both `\ba` and `(?<!\w)a` are similar to both `^a|\Wa` and `(?:^|\W)a` to the point of being occasionally interchangeable, but they are different because the former two match a single character and the latter two can match two. Compare:

```
say '!@a#$' =~ s/\ba//r;         # !@#$

say '!@a#$' =~ s/(?<!\w)a//r;    # !@#$

say '!@a#$' =~ s/^a|\Wa//r;      # !#$

say '!@a#$' =~ s/(?:^|\W)a//r;   # !#$
```

Comment: Another example: `say for '!!a!!' =~ /(!|\ba)/g;`

Comment: If I dont deal with submatches, but only with the whole string match, is my "solution" okay? What do you think? I'm writing a NFA  that only recognizes the L(regex) set.

Comment: No. `say "!a" =~ /^[x!](?:\ba|b)\z/ ? "matched" : "didn't match";`. (This doesn't mean it's impossible to rewrite the pattern without `\b`.)

Comment: Just run it, then replace `\ba` with `(?:^a|\Wa)` and run it again. You'll get different results.

Answer (score 0):

`\ba` will match `a` for the string `!a` 
while `^a|\Wa` will match `!a`

This is the shortest example I can provide why they are NOT equivalent.

Comment: `!` is a non-word  character, so I think you are wrong, regex `\Wa` matches  string `!a`